# GEE App: How to not show the geometry layer after drawing

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am working on a Google Earth Engine app and I would like to allow the user to draw an area of interest polygon (AOI). After drawing, I want to 1) generate the map layer from the drawing geometry layer; 2) not show the geometry layer without removing it. How can I do this? My script below can generate the map layer but cannot hide the geometry layer.

This is the link of my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/775c1ce26c099dce71abb912a31871d1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before end the `chartNdviTimeSeries` function, just include:

dummyGeometry.setShown(false)

[link of example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e34ddc5724808f4b90a3c3aa6c09a39)